# How to get initial location with LocationManager?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I've been getting current location with `GoogleApiClient` up until now but I've just noticed that it's much simpler to do it with `LocationManager` using `LocationListener` since it can even detect when GPS service was turned on or off by the user.

But I have a problem when getting user's first location after the `LocationManager` was initialized.

`LocationManager` has 4 listeners but none of them give you your first location. It does have a `onLocationChanged` listener but it only activates when you move.

This is how I'm using it:

```
// Init LocationManager (needed to track if GPS is turned on or not
locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


end of oncreate......


/*
LocationListener (Listening if GPS service is turned on/off)
 */

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}
```