# Get Location Android

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I have a service that get the location of my phone. When i turn the GPS off and turn it on again, i can't get the location anymore.

Some times it return null the latitude and longitude but GPS is on...

I have a checkbox when i check it, it begin to send to my server the latitude and longitude of my device.

Here is the code. Can someone help me to optimize my code please?

**SERVICE**

```
public class LocalizationService extends Service implements Runnable {

private static final int tempo = (30 * 1000); // 1800
private LocationManager locationManager = null;
private Thread t;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (t == null || !t.isAlive()) {
        t = new Thread(this, "ServicoId: " + startId);
        t.start();
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true) {
        try {
            sendLocation();
            Thread.sleep(tempo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void sendLocation() {

    LatLng latlong = getLocation();

    PolifreteApplication manager = (PolifreteApplication) getApplicationContext();
    Veiculo veiculo = manager.getTransportador().getVeiculo();
    int user = manager.getTransportador().getCodigo();

    if (latlong == null) {

    } else {
        veiculo.setLatitude(latlong.latitude + "");
        veiculo.setLongitude(latlong.longitude + "");

        VeiculoDAL.SendLocationVeiculo(veiculo, user);
    }
}

public LatLng getLocation() {
    // Get the location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    Double lat, lon;
    try {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        return new LatLng(lat, lon);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

**ACTIVITY METHOD**

```
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    if (WebService.conexaoOk()) {

        CheckBox cblocalizacao = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxlocalizacao);

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkboxlocalizacao:
            if (checked && !isGPSEnabled) {
                cblocalizacao.setChecked(false);
                showSettingsAlert();
            } else if (checked && isGPSEnabled) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, LocalizationService.class);
                this.startService(i);
            } else {
                cblocalizacao.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you turn on gps, then you can not get location directly, you can get location after some time.

Comment: refer to this link, it might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237729/how-to-get-initial-location-with-locationmanager/30237809#30237809

Comment: when you restart your gps it looses his fix. It needs a while to get your location back again. Wait some time untill the gps icon on tray stop blinking

Comment: why trying the hard way,when google provides you location example ? Which gives you the location name and pincode

Comment: check this out it really helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android/38897436#38897436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get location from Gps, see this link, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-Gps-location-manager-tutorial/, getting location from Gps is not instantaneous, you need to implement location listener and wait the call back from the Gps provider:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

or you can use network provider

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

Just visit the link, and you will find the best strategy to get the most accurate possible location..

Comment: This tutorial help me alot! Thx.

Comment: it is so bad example ... *`public class GPSTracker extends Service` then `new GPSTracker(...)`* ... It rapes my eyes ... (like other androidhive's "tutorials")

Comment: @Selvin, if its a bad example, could you post a good one? I'm new in android development, i dont know the best pratics...

Comment: try this one :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android ...

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UZaZ7AFQGY) from Udacity gives idea about using the location services in GoogleApiClient.
Since your LocationListener tries to get location using only Network not GPS, with this code snippet: `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)`
probably you are getting latitude and longitude values but with a delay. I had the same problem then I begin to use new/latest Location service API and use:
GoogleApiClient.
First you need to implement

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
```

from you activity that want to fetch the location data.

Define

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

If you haven't add

```
<uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`
```

to the manifest file, add that.

For further documentation : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient

More comprehensive answer about GoogleClientApi:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599343/2644905